# MySQL, sort alphabetically with exception

Tags: mysql

I have a table that is a list of countries, with two fields, ID (int) and country_name. I need to write a query that can pull an alphabetical list of countries, but with the United States record at the top. How can I do this? assume that the id of the united states record = 100.

Comment: As a website user I hate it when websites do this. Its taken as the site owner does not care about visitors from others places (so why ask at all). Just have two options "USA" and "Rest of world" ;-) - my tuppence anyways.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select * 
  from country
 order by case when id = 100 then 0 else 1 end, country_name
```

Extra note.

This solution differs from the other suggested in some ways

- The UNION way. The default behavior of UNION is to remove duplicates, this may or may not be desired ([Unions in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html)). Also unless id is indexed you will have twice the execution time
- The "Select something and do sorting on it" is nice, but returns extra data and depending on the receiving framework this might not be desired.

Answer (score 1):

```
select (case when id = 100 then 1 else 0) presort, country_name from countries order by presort desc, country_name asc
```

Selects a flag aliased presort, which is 1 for id = 100 and 0 for everything else. The selected rows are then sorted descending which puts id = 100 first, then by country_name ascending when presort is 0, which is the case for all other ids.

Comment: Could you please include an explanation of the query?

Comment: @N.N. Sure. :) I hope that's understandable.

Answer (score 0):

```
(SELECT *
FROM countries
WHERE id = 100)
UNION
(SELECT *
FROM countries
WHERE id != 100
ORDER BY country_name)
```

Not necessarily the best way to do it.  I'd prefer to just hard code the USA at the top when using it, in the model layer of sorts.

Answer (score 0):

Do two separate queries using union.

```
select id, country_name from table where id=100
union
select id, country_name from table where id!=100 order by country_name desc;
```

I haven't tested this, but in theory it should work.